# didReceiveLocalNotification triggered when presentLocalNotificationNow is called

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

When I create my local notification callback `didReceiveLocalNotification`gets triggered. The same callback gets triggered when I click on the local notification. Currently I was dividing those two cases by checking

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    //this means notification is clicked
}
```

But the main problem here is that when you are in the foreground and you slide your notification menu, and then receive your local notification, this callback `didReceiveLocalNotification` gets called. And in this case my app goes into this if. Because of this, I can't really distinguish from clicking the notification and creating a local notification while app is in the inactive state. Any ideas on how can I fix this?

This is the code for scheduling a local notification:

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.alertBody = @"aaaa";
localNotification.alertTitle = @"title";
localNotification.userInfo = myUserInfo;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
```

After calling this, I get `didReceiveLocalNotification` delegate triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to work around the exact same issue in my app. I couldn't find an offical way in the API to tell the difference, but here is a workaround.

Pass the current date in the `userInfo` when the local notification is created:

```
localNotification.userInfo = ["alertDate": NSDate()]
```

And when you handle `didReceiveLocalNotification`, check against current date again, to make sure it didn't just fire just a moment ago:

```
if application.applicationState == .Inactive {
    if let alertDate = notification.userInfo?["alertDate"] as? NSDate 
        where (NSDate()).timeIntervalSinceDate(alertDate) > 0.1 {
        // this means notification was initiated by user
    }
}
```

Comment: Really smart idea! Well done, this solves my problem entirely! I have my own user info data, but I created JSON containing 2 fields: One with my data and the other one with the current date, so this worked for me. Thanks a  lot!

Comment: This made my day! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
localNotification.alertBody = @"image inserted";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: How is this related to my question? Showing how to display notification one second after the current time is not useful at all. I need a solution to this problem: I can't really distinguish from clicking the notification and creating a local notification while app is in the inactive state.